# WCF - Windows Credential Caching

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a remote WCF service where I have implemented a custom authorization manager. As part of authorization I grab the windows identity of the client to perform some custom authorization.

The issue I am having is that the client process is running as 'UserA', but when it sends a request to the remote service on ServerX, the service sees 'UserB'.

I have established that this is happening as I have asked windows to cache client credentials for account 'UserB' when I have connected to ServerX at some stage in the past (e.g. via RDP). This is quite a common pattern as many devs have a 'user' account and an 'admin' account and frequently configure windows to cache credentials for their 'admin' accounts when connecting to remote machines.

I know how to manually clear items from the windows credential cache, but how can I prevent WCF from using the cache i.e. so that the client process identity is always used.

Comment: What are you doing to retrieve the client credentials currently?

Comment: @A.R. I am currently using `operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx should help?

Comment: @Chris Not sure how impersonation is going to help out?

Comment: @chibacity I usually use 'ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity' to get the credentials of the caller.  Maybe this will work out for you?

Comment: @A.R. The problem is that a cached credential is being used before the remote service is ever called, so changing to `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` is not going to help.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Do you have any solution?